# Jquery add value input text if hasn´t any value

Tags: jquery

**Hello**

I have input text with start value **"Start Value"**, the idea it´s when put over and click insert one text, but if leave the input text or mouseout of this input text and also if the input text no has value, return to original value **"Start Value"**.

In the other case if insert for example one value as "car", the value always "car", but if delete and input it´s empty return to **"Start Value"**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  /*Initial value*/
  jQuery("#n_select_s").attr("value", "Start Value");

  /*If leave and hasn´t insert value, return original value*/
  jQuery("#n_select_s").mouseleave(function() {
    if (jQuery("#n_select_s").val() == "") {
      jQuery("#n_select_s").attr("value", "Start Value");
    }
  });

  /*If enter mouse and have value delete and insert new value*/
  jQuery("#n_select_s").mouseenter(function() {
    if (jQuery("#n_select_s").val() != "") {
      jQuery("#n_select_s").attr("value", "");
    }
  });

});
```

**Input Text Field**

```html
<input type="text" id="n_select_s" name="number" value="" />
```

But the problem it´s don´t works because if insert text and delete , don´t return to original text **"Start Value"**, i don´t know what´s wrong for don´t get this changes.

**Thank´s in advanced, regards**

Comment: `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` seem like an odd choice, wouldn't events like `change`/`focus`/`blur` make more sense?

Comment: Are you trying to add a `placeholder`? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: No, no placeholder

Comment: Load page load  start value, mouse enter delete value if it´s empty, if leave return original value and if put other value stay because detect exist value and field no empty, the problem it´s when insert with keyboard one value, nothing works, in the moment i insert text the script don´t works, it´s as if the insert text from keyboard most important script tell to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following feature :

```
$("#n_select_s").val("Start Value");
```

or

Use the following attribute :

```
jQuery("#n_select_s").attr("placeholder","Start Value");
```